# Python-docx not recognizing a table

Tags: python-docx, abbyy

I have converted a PDF document to word document using ABBYY finereader.
The table present in the word document is not recognized by python-docx package
Below is the table format:
[image: Sample table]

Below is my piece of code:

```
from docx.api import Document
if __name__=='__main__':
    document = Document('../Data/question.docx')
    table = document.tables
    num_of_tables = (len(table))
    print('num_of_tables ',num_of_tables)
```

The output is

> num_of_tables: 0

Kindly let me know your suggesstions

Comment: I would suspect that the PDF converter inserts the table as a picture.

Comment: No, actually I have taken the image here.

Comment: The table is inserted as text in the docx i.e., in the selectable format. I have taken a screenshot for reference. Is there any alternate approach to extract these value. Kindly let me know